# Why is the responsive grid in tailwind not working on physical device but in responsive design mode?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a grid that transforms into a normal block layout on smaller devices, using [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="md:grid md:gap-3 md:h-screen h-auto md:grid-cols-3 p-5">
        <div
          class="md:col-start-3 h-screen md:h-auto mb-3 block relative rounded-lg md:row-span-2 bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-100 to-gray-50 p-4 text-gray-900 font-semibold"
        >
          Content
        </div>

        <div
          class="md:col-span-2 md:row-start-1 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg p-4 h-screen md:h-auto mb-2"
        >
         Content
        </div>

        <div
          class="md:col-span-1 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg h-screen md:h-auto mb-3"
        >Content</div>
        <div
          class="md:col-span-1 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg h-screen md:h-auto mb-3"
        >Content</div>
      </section>
```

The problem: even though it works in responsive design mode

[image]

It isn't working on an actual iPhone 8:
[image]

[Full project](https://github.com/MoPaMo/mopamo.github.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included this in head?
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: No! Thank you, that was my mistake!